# How to read urls using "With open()"?

Tags: python, image, amazon-web-services, file

I was doing this and worked perfectly fine:

```
def b64_image(filename):
    with open("static/img/"+filename, 'rb') as f:
        b64 = base64.b64encode(f.read())
        return b64.decode('utf-8')
```

But now I uploaded the images to an S3 Bucket so I edited the code:

```
def b64_image(filename):
    with open("https://mybucket.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/" + filename, 'rb') as f:
        b64 = base64.b64encode(f.read())
        return b64.decode('utf-8')
```

And I'm getting the fllowing error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

How can I make this code work? How can I make the code to look for the actual URL image? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use boto3 to access files on S3. Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `open` on files in `S3` you will need to use a 3rd party library. In particular, this maintained and active library, [`smart-open`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open#more-examples) does just that.

Comment: I haven`t used that, but it's definitely an option, thank you!